# Google cloudstorage - Open files using authorization tokens

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to open a file that needs an authorization token for the request, using the cloudstorage api.

Using a token previously defined: 'access_token', my code looks like this:

```
gcs_file = gcs.open(file_path, 'w', options={'Authorization': access_token})
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following error:

```
option Authorization is not supported
```

I guess that I'm not opening this file properly.

Does someone know how should I invoke this function with the token?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you need Authorization? You use app engine and you can access your own cloudstorage files without authorization using the cloudstorage client library for app engine.

Comment: You are completely right! I just wanted to know if it's possible to access external cloudstorage files with the right token. I guess that for security reasons we are not allow to do that! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access buckets and objects that don't belong to your project, so long as your app's service account has been granted access. If you have literally been handed a valid OAuth 2 access token and want to use that, you could use the [Google API Python Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/), which can use the [oauth2client.client.AccessTokenCredentials](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#AccessTokenCredentials) class to authenticate with an access token.

I'm curious, though. Where did your app get ahold of an access token and why do you want to use it?

Comment: I was just curious about gathering external files with the cloudstorage api with the right token.